# R group data into equal groups with a metric variable

Tags: r, grouping

I'm struggeling to get a good performing script for this problem: I have a table with a score, x, y. I want to sort the table by score and than build groups based on the x value. Each group should have an equal sum (not counts) of x. x is a metric number in the dataset and resembles the historic turnover of a customer.

```
      score x   y
0.436024136 3   435
0.282303336 46  56
0.532358015 24  34
0.644236597 0   2
0.99623626  0   4
0.557673456 56  46
0.08898779  0   7
0.702941303 453 2
0.415717835 23  1
0.017497461 234 3
0.426239166 23  59
0.638896238 234 86
0.629610596 26  68
0.073107526 0   35
0.85741877  0   977
0.468612039 0   324
0.740704267 23  56
0.720147257 0   68
0.965212467 23  0
```

Comment: There are some suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424130/creating-groups-of-equal-sum-in-r

Comment: How do you determine the number of groups you would like to have?

Comment: @Georgery: the number of groups are given. In my case I build 10. But the number of records per group divers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a good way to do so is adding a group variable to the data.frame with cumsum! Now you can easily sum the groups with e. g. subset.

```
data.frame$group <-cumsum(as.numeric(data.frame$x)) %/% (ceiling(sum(data.frame$x) / 3)) + 1
```

remarks:

- in big `data.frames cumsum(as.numeric())` works reliably
- `%/%` is a division where you get an integer back
- the '+1' just let your groups start with 1 instead of 0

thank you @Ronak Shah!